# Why is my name method undefined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am receiving a undefined method `name' for # error for my Rails project. I know that name is defined for events by double checking using my console, so I don't understand why it won't load. Here is some of my code:

**Apps Show:**

```
<h1><%= @app.title %></h1>
<h5>App URL: <%= @app.url %></h5>
<h5>App User_id: <%= @app.user_id %></h5>
<br>

    <h2> Events </h2>
      <% @events.each do |event| %>
        <div>
          <%= event.name %><span class="badge"><%= event.count %></span>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    <br>
    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_app_path(@app), class: 'btn btn-success' %>
```

**Apps Controller:**

```
class AppsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @app = App.new(params.require(:app).permit(:title, :url))
    @app.user_id = 1
    if @app.save
      flash[:notice] = "App was saved!"
      redirect_to @app
    else
      flash[:error] = "There an error, oh noes!Please try again!"
      render :new
    end
  end

  def new
    @app = App.new
  end

  def show
    @app = App.find(params[:id])
    @events = @app.events.group_by(&:name)
  end

  def index
    @apps = App.all
  end

  def edit
    @app = App.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @app = App.find(params[:id])
     if @app.update_attributes(params.require(:app).permit(:title, :url))
       flash[:notice] = "Application was updated."
       redirect_to @app
     else
       flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the app. Please try again."
       render :edit
     end
  end

  def destroy
    @app = App.find(params[:id])
    if @app.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "App was removed."
      redirect_to @app
    else
      flash[:error] = "App couldn't be deleted. Try again."
      redirect_to @app
    end

     respond_to do |format|
       format.html
       format.js
     end
  end
end
```

**Events Seed:**

```
create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "app_id"
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

**App Model:**

```
class App < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :events
end
```

Complete Error Log:

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 19ms

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `name' for #<Array:0x007fcc53394af0>):
     6: <h2> Events </h2>
     7:   <% @events.each do |event| %>
     8:     <div>
     9:       <%= event.name %><span class="badge"><%= event.count %></span>
    10:     </div>
    11:   <% end %>
    12: <br>
  app/views/apps/show.html.erb:9:in `block in _app_views_apps_show_html_erb__2949113196422864311_70257764571040'
  app/views/apps/show.html.erb:7:in `each'
  app/views/apps/show.html.erb:7:in `_app_views_apps_show_html_erb__2949113196422864311_70257764571040'


  Rendered /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (7.1ms)
  Rendered /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (4.1ms)
  Rendered /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/template_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (71.2ms)
  Rendered /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.1.3/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.1.3/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.1.3/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.1.3/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.1.3/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (69.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.1.3/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.1.3/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/ericpark/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.1.3/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (156.5ms)
```

Comment: What's the structure of your `App` model?

Comment: Can you post your complete log error?

Comment: Yup just added the model and complete log error in my edits.

Answer (score 1):

In cases like this, simple debug printing will reveal the problem. Is `name` not defined on `@events` when you think it should be? Are you sure that `@events` is what you think it is?

Add `p @events` line to your controller, retry the request and read the log. A piece of advice for the future. :)

The problem starts here:

```
@events = @app.events.group_by(&:name)
```

I'm pretty sure that output of `group_by` is a hash, where keys are different names and values are arrays of events which all have the same name. (depends on what exactly the implementation of `group_by` is, of course)

```
<% @events.each do |event| %>
```

`event` here is not an instance of `Event` class, but a two element array, `[name, [event1, event2, ...]]`. You should iterate this nested array to get real events, which do have the method you want.

```
<% @events.each do |name, events| %>
  <%= name %> <%= events.length %>
```

Comment: Thanks Sergio, for trying to explain the issue to me. Just to clarify what does the p @events do when I add it to my controller. I just added it, and it doesn't seem to have any output? Would that be in my terminal? Sorry still new to rails.

Comment: Yeah, it'll go to the terminal. `p @events` is equal to `puts @events.inspect` which prints detailed representation of the object.

Comment: gotcha, so the output I recieved was ```{"Fugiat sunt eaque aliquid asperiores culpa aut saepe molestias."=>[#<Event id: 23, app_id: 5, name: "Fugiat sunt eaque aliquid asperiores culpa aut sae...", created_at: "2015-07-10 15:35:07", updated_at: "2015-07-10 15:35:07">], "Velit deleniti eligendi commodi."=>[#<Event id: 48, app_id: 5, name: "Velit deleniti eligendi commodi.", created_at: "2015-07-10 15:35:07", updated_at: "2015-07-10 15:35:07">]}```. Seeing that its a hash, I would need to access it differently

Comment: @EricPark: yeah, added an example

Comment: BTW, I highly recommend `awesome_print` gem for this kind of debug printing. Check it out sometime. It really is awesome :)

Answer (score 1):

@events is hash you have to iterate like

```
   <% @events.each do |event| %>
    <div>
      <%= event[0] %><span class="badge"><%= event[1].count %></span>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```